# Can't load files from ancestor folders using the include() php function

Tags: php, include

When I include files from the same folder, for example

```
include('Car.php');
```

It works perfectly, but if I move it one folder back and change the include to

```
include('../Car.php');
```

It returns the following message:

> Warning: include(../Car.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/user/Desktop/Test/clases/Bus.php on line 1
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../Car.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in /Users/user/Desktop/Test/clases/Bus.php on line 1

This is my folder structure:

- Tests/

  - Car.php
  - clases/

    - Bus.php

I'm trying to include the Car.php from the Bus.php.

Comment: which file do you move back ? and in which folder do you have car.php ?

Comment: I edited the question, check it

Comment: try : ***include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../Car.php');***

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using php 5.3 try using

```
clearstatcache(true);
include realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Car.php');
//alternative
//include realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Car.php');
```

And see if that resolves your issue.

Explanation of functionality

`clearstatcache(true)` will delete the PHP cache of realpath and can generally be removed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

`realpath` checks the file existence and expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' or returns false on failure. http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

`__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` is the full path to the current directory, instead of relying on PHP's include path to determine where the file is located.

`/../` tells the full path to traverse up one directory, which `realpath` will translate to the actual path and remove the relative connotation.

The main issue is probably your php.ini include path since include relies on it if it is not able to find the path of the included file.
It is considered best practice to include `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` when calling include or require so as to not rely on the configured php include path location, which in large applications can be considerably slower than explicitly defining the path information.

Include path information: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: It worked! Can you explain me a little bit more about it? Because I remember using include('../Car.php') a lot of times in the past :S